# Saving input from default popup in chrome.storage and using in content script - getting null values

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, infinite-loop

I am writing a chrome extension that takes in input through the default popup, saves it in chrome.storage, and then notifies the content script with message passing and modifies the DOM. It appears to be in an infinite loop.

I'm not sure if I'm using chrome.storage incorrectly or message passing incorrectly, but when the script for the popup tries to run an onclick function it thinks the button is null (perhaps because it doesn't exist yet when the page first loads?)

Here is all of the code and the errors/print statements I'm getting - if anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate it!

***popup.js***

```
console.log("loaded popup");

    document.getElementById("save-button").onclick = function(){
        console.log("added click function");
        var value = document.getElementById('new-filter').value;
        value = value.trim();
        console.log("value saved is " + value);
        if(value !== ''){
        chrome.storage.sync.set({'myFilter': value}, function(){
                alert("Success!");
                chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
                  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "new filter saved"}, function(response) {
                    console.log(response.farewell);
                  });
                });

        });
        }
    }
```

***Console for popup***

```
loaded popup
popup.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
```

***popup.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crafty+Girls' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>


<title>Filter</title>
</head>

<body>    
<form method="get">
 <input type="text" name="filter" title="new filter" id = "new-filter" style="color:#888; text-align:center;" placeholder="new filter"><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Save" id="save-button">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

***script.js***

```
var Node = {}
Node.ELEMENT_NODE = 1;
Node.DOCUMENT_NODE = 9;
Node.DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE = 11;
Node.TEXT_NODE = 3;

    console.log("loaded script.js");
    walkWithFilter();


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "new filter saved") {
        walkWithFilter();
      // sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    }
  });

function walkWithFilter(){
    chrome.storage.sync.get('myFilter', function(e){
            var word = e.myFilter;
            console.log(word);
            if(word !== null){
                walk(document.body, word);
            }
        });
}


function walk(node, filter) {
    console.log("value of filter in walk "+ filter + " node: " + node);
    var child, next;
    if(node !== null && filter !== undefined) {

        switch (node.nodeType) {
            case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:  // Element
            case Node.DOCUMENT_NODE:  // Document
            case Node.DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE: // Document fragment
                child = node.firstChild;


            while (child, filter) {
                next = child.nextSibling;
                walk(child, filter);
                child = next;
            }

            break;

            case Node.TEXT_NODE: // Text node
            hide(node, filter);
            break;
    }
    }//if statement
}

function hide(textNode, filter) {
    var nodeValue = textNode.nodeValue;

    for (var i=0; i < filter.length; i++) {
        if(-1 != nodeValue.indexOf(filter[i])) {

            textNode.parentNode.classList.add('filter');

            //how to change the element by class name (test)
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName('filter');
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                console.log("parent length loop");
                x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
                 $('.filter').parent().parent().parent().parent().addClass("parent-filter");    
                    $('.parent-filter').hide();
                    $('.parent-filter').css("background-color", "black");

                }
             $('.filter').parent().css("background-color", "red");

        }
    }
    textNode.nodeValue = nodeValue;
}
```

***Console for script.js***

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
//(above error only when I reload the page)

Navigated to https://twitter.com/
loaded script.js
BuzzFeed //(value in storage)
value of filter in walk BuzzFeed node: [object HTMLBodyElement]
script.js:65value of filter in walk BuzzFeed node: [object HTMLInputElement]
value of filter in walk BuzzFeed node: [object HTMLInputElement]
extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8Error in response to storage.get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextSibling' of null
    at walk (chrome-extension://aaeakggdedckekhmnijejajggkhekpdh/script.js:77:17)
    at walk (chrome-extension://aaeakggdedckekhmnijejajggkhekpdh/script.js:78:5)
    at Object.callback (chrome-extension://aaeakggdedckekhmnijejajggkhekpdh/script.js:28:5)
    at walkWithFilter (chrome-extension://aaeakggdedckekhmnijejajggkhekpdh/script.js:24:22)
    at chrome-extension://aaeakggdedckekhmnijejajggkhekpdh/script.js:9:2handler @ extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8(anonymous function) @ extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:100safeCallbackApply @ extensions::sendRequest:23handleResponse @ extensions::sendRequest:72
```